# What is the application of ReceiveAll() in Corda? How to implement it?

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, corda

Is there any examples available which implemented sentAll() and receiveAll()?

> receiveAll(receiveType: Class, sessions: List): List<UntrustworthyData>

In [doc](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/api-flows.html#communication-between-parties) it says : Receives from all **FlowSession** objects specified in the passed in list. The received types must be the same.

Is it used inside responder flow? If so, how to input the needed session as list in receiveAll()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> receiveAll() & sendAll() are actually performance upgrades in 4.5
> version.

Giving two examples here:

- If you want to send a message from A to B/C that initiates new sessions, you'll use initiateFlow for B and C and then do a **sendAll()** from party A. On the responder side on B and C, you'll do a plain receive.
- If you want to receive in parallel messages from B & C in party A (say after establishing the sessions), you can do a plain send from B and C, and a **receiveAll()** from A.

**Initiator Flow:**

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class sendAllReceiveAllExampleFlow(private val itemToBeSent : String) : FlowLogic<String>(){
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() : String {
        val counterParty1 = serviceHub.identityService.partiesFromName("PartyB",false).single()
        val counterParty2 = serviceHub.identityService.partiesFromName("PartyC",false).single()

        val counterPartySession1 = initiateFlow(counterParty1)
        val counterPartySession2 = initiateFlow(counterParty2)

        sendAll(itemToBeSent, setOf(counterPartySession1,counterPartySession2))

        val receivedBack= receiveAll(String::class.java,listOf(counterPartySession1,
counterPartySession2)).map { it.unwrap { it } }

  
       return "receivedBack :" + receivedBack.toString()
    }
}
```

**Responder Flow:**

```
class SendAllReceiveAllResponder(private val counterSessionList : FlowSession): FlowLogic<Unit>(){
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(){
        println("Inside Responder ")
        val receivedString = counterSessionList.receive<String>().unwrap { it }
        println("PayLoad Received at Responder = "+ receivedString)
        counterSessionList.send(receivedString + ourIdentity.name.organisation)
    }
}
```

Source of case scenarios: [CordaLedger-Slack](https://cordaledger.slack.com/archives/C2KGD72UX/p1601994702304500)

Comment: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.7/core-tests/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/coretests/flows/ReceiveAllFlowTests.kt.  Example test file using receiveAll()

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look to this unit test - [FlowParallelMessagingTests.kt](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/da73cbf2a5404d0720334b62d6f7f119d85caf45/node/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/statemachine/FlowParallelMessagingTests.kt) -  in the Corda repository on github.

Also, to add something about this API, there are two APIs that allow you to send messages to multiple sessions at the same time:

- with `SendAll()` you send **the same payload** to all the sessions, as showed also in the previous comment too;
- with `SendAllMap()` you can send different payloads to different sessions at the same time. An example is in the link I provided above.